# Selenium and Database testing

Tags: selenium, testing, automation

I am totally new to the web application and automation testing.
I am learning selenium from youtube videos and developing frameworks.
while looking into the videos most of them cover only testing the Application as such.

I found very few videos which state about interacting with the database and verifying them.
I just wanted to know how will this be in real time projects?
In real time projects will they automating scenarios like configuring something in the UI, then validating it in the database, coming back to the UI and continuing the UI flow or will it be simply only verifying the UI.

I want to know more about how to do database testing.

Any info here will be of great help

Comment: What kind of info are you expecting here? Can you share with us some of your work please? Thanks

Comment: I want to know in real time projects what will be the scenario with respect to using Selenium in Automation Testing, will it be a simply used for testing  the web application or will it be used for both Database and Web application Testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Selenium** is one of the best choice available in today's market when it boils down to *Automation of Web Application*. Selenium have support for Mozilla'a `geckodriver`, Google's `chromedriver`, Microsoft's `IEDriverServer` & even `Safari` etc. Hence Selenium is widely accepted as the best Web Automation tool as of today.

Having said that, though you too can perform `Database Testing` through Selenium but it's not the ideal candidate. `Database Testin`g can include `transaction rates` & `round-trip` calculations for which there are other tools which does those work better and you may like to explore those as well. Alternatively, you can also integrate those tools in your Project Framework and work with Selenium in tandem.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what i was looking for !